# Primefaces icons not showing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I just bought a hosting plan for my web app, got it up and running but I noticed that the PrimeFaces icons aren't showing up.
for example this table should have a search icon on the right button.

[image: Example]

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{someBean.someAction}"
   title="Show data"> </p:commandButton>
```

Hosted on my local machine (windows + firefox/chrome) is working fine, although on my mac (+chrome/safari) isn't working either.

Comment: What did you debug?

Comment: GET domain_dotsomething/ App_name/javax.faces.resource/ images/ ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what do other clients show?

Comment: did you try to replace icon by image to see if there is something différente ?!?